# Does molten potassium wet steel?

Tags: material-science, physical-chemistry

I'm designing a device that uses molten potassium in steel pipes. If the device cools, the potassium will solidify and shrink, and if it's adhered strongly to the pipes I'm worried they may crack, so I was wondering if potassium wets steel.

Comment: I suspect the solid potassium would crack much sooner than the (stainless) steel.

Comment: No, I think it doesn't.

Comment: The potassium metal solid is about as strong as cold butter, it would not matter if it stuck to the pipe. You could be using a thin-walled *lead* pipe, and the pipe would still be the stronger element by far.

Comment: Make sure that you don't "block in" the potassium such that it can't expand upon heating, using both strict procedures and rupture disks.  Potassium has a higher coefficient of linear expansion than steel (based on an internet search), so when it cools, it shrinks more than steel, but when it warms, it expands more than steel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous commenters are correct--potassium is exceedingly soft and should not pose a significant mechanical hazard to steel. Molten alkali metals are often used as coolant in nuclear reactors, where they are contained within steel components without any mechanical problems. *Chemical* safety, of course, should be your major concern with this design, as potassium will react violently with oxygen or water.

As an aside, the eutectic NaK alloy (about 79% potassium, 21% sodium) is actually liquid at room temperature; so this may eliminate the solidification problem altogether, unless you're dealing with cryogenic temperatures.

Comment: Molten potassium does not wet steel indeed. I know this from handling molten alkali metals myself.